# Input loses focus when I use focus( function(){} )

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete input field that is hidden until I click an item. In order to avoid having the user to click the inputbox, I want to use `.focus()`.

Using this alone works. The probloem is that when I start typing, the autocomplete is not working. So I have to trigger the autocompelte functions. The functions I use is this:

```
self.find('.search-city').on('focus', function(){
    $(this).acCity(); // Custom function for autocomplete
});
```

The problem is that as soon as I use `function()` it loses focus. [You can see the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/totgn883/1/).

How can this be resolved?

Comment: What's there in the `.acCity`?

Comment: You are registering an event handler within an event handler (never a good idea) :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Why not?

Comment: Every time you click you will add the handler another time, so it will fire 2, 3 4 then 5 times etc. If you actually want a handler there turn it `off` then `on` again (instead of using click).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are registering a focus event handler instead of calling `focus()` which sets focus on the element.

*Assuming* you want both it would be more like this http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/totgn883/3:

```
$('.container').on('click', function(){
    var self = $(this);
    self.find('.city').hide();
    self.find('.input-wrapper').addClass('show');
    self.find('.search-city').focus(); // Works fine
});

// Listen for a focus event - does not cause focus to occur
$('.search-city').focus( function(){
        // Does not work
    console.log("I am focused");
});
```

**Note:** Going by the comment below you seem to think `$('.search-city').focus( function(){` fires a focus event. It does not. It registers a function to be called when the element actually gets focused.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's wrong. The way you do it, the `.search-city` gets focus once the page loads, not when the container is clicked.

Comment: @Steven: Any particular reason you feel it is *wrong*? http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/totgn883/3/ You need to provide the full page HTML and possibly explain the aim of the code too if there are other controls that may clash :)

Comment: ;) Just me thinking that this would trigger on page load. But of course, it will only trigger on focus :)

Comment: @Steven: If there is still a problem, please explain the desired result of the code. Cheers :)

Comment: It works fine. Up till now I've triggered the autocomplete function on input click event. Triggering it on focus event seems like a much better idea. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use callback function syntax:

```
.focus(function () {
    // Does not work
});
```

you [bind an event](http://api.jquery.com/focus/), not fire it.

In you case you should simply trigger focus event with a call `.focus()` (or `.trigger('focus')`).

Comment: You would not register a `focus` event handler inside a `click` event handler.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Of course, that's why I stated `although you don't want to do that in your case`. But you are right, it's confusing, I will remove this part.

Comment: @dfsq, It was more understandable with your previous code. Using this works: `self.find('.search-city').focus(function(){
 $(this).val('');
 $(this).acCity();
}).trigger('focus');`

Comment: yes, but you should not bind event handlers inside other event handlers. Because after 3 clicks focus handler will execute 3 times in a row.